# ReactJS -> Why is my localstorage storing the items in such a way?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, list, object

So I have a localstorage setter and getter that are inside a useEffect function that look like this:

```
useEffect(() => {


        localStorage.setItem('products', JSON.stringify(product))

})

useEffect(()=>{
    setProduct([...product,JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('products'))])


},[])
```

and then I save them into an array using the setProduct that I've declared here:

```
    const [product, setProduct]= useState([])
```

and whenever I console log the product array it returns me the array, in the console, in the following format:

```
Array(1)
  0: Array(5)
   0: Array(4)
     0:
       Image: "/static/media/Dress.1c414114.png"
       Price: 540
       id: 0
       name: "Blue Dress"
       __proto__: Object
     1:
       Price: 600
       id: 1
       image: "/static/media/Dress.1c414114.png"
       name: "Red Dress"
       __proto__: Object
```

My question is why does it show itself in such a format and how can I make it look like this:

```
Array(1)
     0:
       Image: "/static/media/Dress.1c414114.png"
       Price: 540
       id: 0
       name: "Blue Dress"
       __proto__: Object
     1:
       Price: 600
       id: 1
       image: "/static/media/Dress.1c414114.png"
       name: "Red Dress"
       __proto__: Object
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `JSON.parse` returns an array.

```
setProduct([...product,JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('products'))])
```

will create an array containing `product`, plus another array, the local storage item.

Spread the local storage item instead.

```
setProduct([...product, ...JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('products'))])
```

Or just keep it in memory

```
const [product, setProduct]= useState(JSON.getItem('products') || []);
useEffect(() => {
  localStorage.setItem('products', JSON.stringify(product));
}, [product])
```

and use `product` and `setProduct` normally

Comment: Thank you for your answer, just a little question since I am new to react, what would be considered using product and setproduct normally?

Comment: As in, outside of the final code block, don't reference `localStorage` anywhere else. Calling `setProducts` will then automatically update the storage data.